# EF: Invalid column name 'Party_ID'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I am using code first approach in Entity Framework. I am getting the following errors.

> Invalid column name 'Party_ID'.  exec sp_executesql N'INSERT
>   [dbo].[PartyCellPhone]([ID], [Party_ID],   [CountryCode], [Number]) 
>   VALUES (@0, NULL, NULL, @1)  ',N'@0 int,@1 nvarchar(max)
>   ',@0=13,@1=N'1234546877'
>
> InnerException = {"Invalid column name 'Party_ID'."}

```
 public abstract class PartyContact:BaseModel
    {
        public PartyContact()
        {

        }

        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        //public Enums.ContactType ContactType { get; set; }
        //public Enums.ContactUsage ContactUsage { get; set; }

        public abstract Enums.ContactMethod ContactMethod { get; }
        public  int ContactTypeID { get; set; }
        public  int ContactUsageID { get; set; }
        public int ContactMethodID { get; set; }
        public int PartyID { get; set; }
        public abstract bool Validate();
        [ForeignKey("PartyID")]
        public virtual Party Party { get; set; }
    }

 public class CellPhone : PartyContact, ICellPhone
    {
      public string CountryCode { get; set; }
      public string Number { get; set; }

      public override Enums.ContactMethod ContactMethod
       {
         get
          {
            return  Enums.ContactMethod.Cell;
          }
       }
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the ContactNumber class with default values.
    /// </summary>
    public CellPhone()
    {
    }

    }
```

When I call the save method, it is showing me this error. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: No EF expert here, but have you confirm the name is Party_ID on the DB? Your references here have PartyId

Answer (score 0):

The Code-First convention for foreign key property expects your `PartyContact` class to have a matching property of your `Party` class. I'm guessing you have `Party_ID` as the primary key of your `Party` class.

Do this

```
public int Party_ID { get; set; }
public virtual Party Party { get; set; }
```

Or this, if for some reason you want to name your foreign key differently than your `Party` class' ID.

```
[ForeignKey("Party_ID")]
public int PartyID { get;set; }
public virtual Party Party { get; set; }
```